# Are there any alternatives for an IFrame if I need to load an external url to my webpage

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I need to know if there are any alternatives for an IFrame that I could use to load in an external URL into my webpage. Even if it's JQuery or JavaScript or PHP

Comment: dynamic or just at page load ?

Comment: just page load, just need to load an external url

Answer (score 1):

You define a container in your page such as:

```
<div id="external"></div>
```

then you fill it with an AJAX call via jQuery:

```
$('#external').load("http://remote.page/");
```

EDIT: as pointed out by Graza in the comment, this won't work if the external page is on another domain due to the limitation on XMLHttpRequest objects -- if you need that you'll have to do a JSONP request, which requires cooperation on the server side. See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) for more information.

Comment: This wouldn't work if "remote.page" was from a different domain would it?

Comment: when i tried this showing error

i tried to load page from different domain

Answer (score 1):

Be so careful doing this though, make sure you absolutely trust the 3rd party site.  If they inject javascript into your page, it will be running under the same context as your own site, which could lead to all sorts of hackery followed by only tears and sadness.  IFrames give you a certain amount of protection for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.load()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

Example:

```
$("#feeds").load("feeds.html");
```

Comment: be careful, as this will load the whole html, including html and body tags which should not be repeated in a page ..

Comment: scrap my above comment.. .load takes care of that .. (it only brings elements in the body tag..)